# Enabling system AHB clock to timer

Tags: timer, cpu-registers

I am trying to understand SPI communication code written for LPC11U14 MCU and Murata gyro sensor. I myself have an experience with Arduino, heard about pointers and shift registers and currently learning C programming for fun.

[Full code in PDF](https://www.murata.com/~/media/webrenewal/products/sensor/pdf/specification/spicommunication_scc2000.ashx?la=en-us)

[MCU header file](https://os.mbed.com/users/screamer/code/mbed/docs/tip/LPC11Uxx_8h_source.html).

This line assigning timer is not clear for me:
`LPC_SYSCON->SYSAHBCLKCTRL |= (1 << 7);`

What I understood `SYSAHBCLKCTRL` is a system AHB clock control Register. `LPC_SYSCON` is a pointer to clock register. But how does is enables the clock by shifting register 7 bit left? Is this register defined in datasheet?

Excerpt from code:

```
// Enable AHB clock to the 16-bit counter/timer 0 (CT16B0)
LPC_SYSCON->SYSAHBCLKCTRL |= (1 << 7);
// MR0 (Match Register 0) will generate an interrupt at 2300 Hz (MCLK is 48 MHz)
LPC_CT16B0->MR0 = 20870;
LPC_CT16B0->MCR = (0x3 << 0); // Interrupt and Reset on MR0
NVIC_EnableIRQ(TIMER_16_0_IRQn); // Enable the TIMER0 Interrupt
LPC_CT16B0->TCR = 1; // Enable TIMER0
```

P.S. Maybe an example in "Arduino language" could help also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LPC_SYSCON` is a pointer that points to the base address of `SYSCON` which I think is a hardware block in your MCU. The data structure that starts from the base address is well defined in the header file named `LPC_SYSCON_Type`. `LPC_SYSCON->SYSAHBCLKCTRL` uses that base address and offset of register `SYSAHBCLKCTRL` to calculate the physical address of `SYSAHBCLKCTRL`, then set the bit 7 by `|= (1 << 7)` (bit 7 is surely the AHB clock enable bit).